# Add - select from list to a dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Having created dropdown lists using ViewBag which is working in an edit form. How would you add a  “select from list” on the dropdown, at present it displays a blank space?
Where to put the “select from list”  - controller or view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an overload of the DropDownList/DropDownListFor helper which allows you to add a default value:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedId,
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Items, // <= yuck, use a view model instead of ViewBag/ViewCrap
    "select from list"
)
```